# Ajax submit result opens in admin-ajax.php

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, ajax

I have a plugin to submit a form via ajax.

I have this as the js:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#form_id').submit(function() {
                                e.preventDefault();
                var $form = $(this);
                $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(data) {
$('#feedback_id').html(data);
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The HTML of the form is like:

```
$action=admin_url('admin-ajax.php');

  <form method='post' action='$action'  id='form_id'>
<ul><li><input type='text' name='dname'  placeholder='Name'  />
</li><li><input type='email' name='email' class='field-style field-split align-left'  /></li>
<li>
<input type='hidden' name='action' value='php_function'/>
<input type='submit' value='SUBMIT' />
</li>
</ul>
</form>
<div id='feedback_id'></div>
```

There is a function php_function() to process the form input.
Every other thing is in place:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_php_function', 'php_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_php_function', 'php_function');
```

**The output is supposed to be displayed in the div with id feedback_id but it 
opens and shows up in the page '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'**

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing the event object in your submit function, so `e.preventDefault();` doesn't stop the form from being submitted.

```
$('#form_id').submit(function(e) { // <--- event object 'e'
    e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Have added the e in the bracket. Still same behavior.

Comment: Look at your browser's error console for javascript errors. If you're using the built in version of jQuery, `$(document).ready(function()` should be `jQuery(document).ready(function($)`.

Comment: Thanks. Working now. Though I had to remove the **$** from **var $form** .